# Swift Vapor add additional info to custom response

Tags: swift, vapor

I've two Models, Trip and Location. I would return a custom response with some field of trip and the number of Location that has the tripID equal to id of Trip. There is my code(not working). The field locationCount is always empty.

```
func getList(_ request: Request)throws -> Future<Response> {

    let deviceIdReq = request.parameters.values[0].value
    let queryTrips = Trip.query(on: request).filter(\.deviceId == deviceIdReq).all()
    var tripsR = [TripCustomContent]()
    var trips = [Trip]()

    return queryTrips.flatMap { (result) -> (Future<Response>) in
        trips = result

        var count = 0
        for t in trips {
            let tripIdString = String(t.id!)
            let v = Location.query(on: request).filter(\.tripID == tripIdString).count().map({ (res) -> Int in
                return res
            })/*.map{ (result) -> (Int) in
             count = result
             return result
             }*/
            let tripCustomContent = TripCustomContent.init(startTimestamp: t.startTimestamp, endTimestamp: t.endTimestamp, deviceId: t.deviceId, locationCount: v)
            tripsR.append(tripCustomContent)
        }
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let data = try jsonEncoder.encode(tripsR)
        let response = HTTPResponse.init(status: .ok, version: HTTPVersion.init(major: x, minor: y), headers: HTTPHeaders.init(), body: data)
        let finalResponse = Response.init(http: response, using: request)
        return try g.encode(for: request)
    }
}
```

and this is my custom content struct:

```
struct TripCustomContent: Encodable {
var startTimestamp: String?
var endTimestamp: String?
var deviceId: String
var locationCount: Future<Int>
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a value which isn't available yet. When you're returning a `Future`, you aren't returning the value inside it.

So you want your `TripCustomContent` to be like this (use in vapor `Content` instead of `Codable`:

```swift
struct TripCustomContent: Content {
    var startTimestamp: String?
    var endTimestamp: String?
    var deviceId: String
    var locationCount: Int
}
```

You queried the `Trip` correctly, but not the `Location`. You could maybe try something like this:

```swift
return queryTrips.flatMap { trips -> Future<[TripCustomContent]> in
    let tripIds = trips.map({ String($0.id!) })
    return Location.query(on: request).filter(\.tripID ~~ tripIds).all().map { locations in
        return trips.map { trip in
            let locationCount = locations.filter({ $0.tripId == String(trip.id!) }).count
            return TripCustomContent(... locationCount: locationCount)
        }
    }
}
```

What did I do here?

1. Map the trips to their tripIds to get an array of tripIds
2. Get all locations with a tripId of one of the tripIds in the above array
3. Map each of the trips to an instance of `TripCustomContent`, using the locations of the database filtered by `tripId`

Finally, you don't need to encode the JSON yourself, just return objects conforming `Content`:

`func getList(_ request: Request) throws -> Future<[TripCustomContent]>`

---

The above could be a solution to your strategy. But maybe you take a look at [relations](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/fluent/relations/) if they can be a more efficient, easier and faster way.

Comment: Awesome! it's clear! Only one question. In this line: 
 .filter(\.tripID ~~ tripIds).all()
i'm comparing one value with an array. Seems not working

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. It's the [subset filter, look here](https://api.vapor.codes/fluent/latest/Fluent/Functions.html#/s:6Fluent2ttoiyAA14FilterOperatorVyxq_Gs7KeyPathCyq_q0_G_Sayq0_GtAA15QuerySupportingRzSER0_r1_lF).

Comment: oh ok. Sorry, i'm new in Vapor. Thanks, you are great!!